# Get rabbitmq message body

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am using RabbitMQ 3.1.3 to handle Celery tasks, and have discovered a task that is locking up my workers.  It is one of two messages in a queue, and I would love to see the content of the message to debug what is breaking my process flow.  How can I dump the message body for debugging purposes?  I have tried rabbitmqadmin, but get "Connection reset" errors on login attempt (and the logs show a cryptic "{bad_header,<<"POST /ap">>}
").

Answer (score 0):

Login to the web managemnet gui at the RabbitMQ server to view the status of your server in an easy way. You can see exchanges, queues etc. And the status of the messages.

I would also recommend you to check out the tutorials at the RabbitMq website. They explain how everything works in a compact way it is also code examples for several programming languages. Php, Java, Ruby etc

You can easily write small programs to test queues, sending test messages etc from the examples.

Comment: Seriously? He has a very specific question about an obviously up and running message broker, so your "RTFM" response is not helpful.